# RAD Studio - Open an exe file on button click

Tags: c++, firemonkey

I am using FMX. Does anyone know how I can run an `.exe` file in a button click? There is not enough resources on this issue.

I am trying

```
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE NativeUInt __fastcall FileOpen('Console\app.exe');
```

But honestly, I wasn't able to see a working example.

**UPDATE:** The full code is this:

```cpp
#include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <shellapi.h>
#include "MainStartWindow.h"
#include "LandingWindow.h"
#include "Login.h"
#include "Register.h"
#include "TempDashboard.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TLandingWin *LandingWin;

__fastcall TLandingWin::TLandingWin(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}

void __fastcall TLandingWin::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
    // if LandingWin gets closed by X, startWin gets closed as well
    startWin->Close();
}

void __fastcall TLandingWin::landingLoginButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    LoginWin->Show();
    RegisterWin->Close();
    //LandingWin->Hide();
}

void __fastcall TLandingWin::landingRegisterButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
     RegisterWin->Show();
     LoginWin->Close();
}

void __fastcall TLandingWin::guestLoginButton2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    HINSTANCE result = ShellExecuteW(Handle, NULL, L"\\Console\\app.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    if (int(result) > 32)
    {
        // success...
    }
    else
    {
        // error...
    }

     LandingWin->Hide();
}
```

Any idea why I get this error?

> shellapi.h(88): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Fmx::Types::TWindowHandle *' to 'HWND' (aka 'HWND__ *') for 1st argument

Comment: Does "open an .exe" mean _"run the program"_ or _"read the contents of the file"_?  `FileOpen` does the later.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to click on a `TButton` in your application and that  you'd like to start another program in the `OnClick` event handler?

Comment: Note that `\a` in `Console\app.exe` means [audible bell](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Comment: Also note that in C++, `'Console\app.exe'` is a multi-byte character literal, not a string. Unlike in Delphi, which uses `'` for both characters and strings, in C++ you need `'` for characters and `"` for strings. And you need to escape ```\``` in literals in C++, eg: `"Console\\app.exe"`

Comment: run another program, yes

Comment: @murtdoc Then `FileOpen()` is the wrong way to accomplish that. Use [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) instead.

Comment: How can I use createProcess() in Rad Studio?

Comment: @murtdoc Just call it like any other function. What is the problem? There are a bazillion examples of this online.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just post the code above, in the question section

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `'Console\app.exe'` is a multi-byte character literal, not a string literal. Unlike in Delphi, which uses `'...'` for both character literals and string literals, in C++ you need `'...'` for character literals and `"..."` for string literals. And, in both cases, you need to escape the `\` character used in literals in C++ (you don't need to in Delphi), eg: `"Console\\app.exe"`.

Now, that said, you stated that you want to "*run*" another program.  `FileOpen()` is not the way to accomplish that.  It just opens the file so you can access its raw data.

On Windows, use the Win32 [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) function instead, eg:

```cpp
#ifdef _Windows
#include <windows.h>
#else
// include other platform headers as needed...
#endif

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    #ifdef _Windows

    STARTUPINFOW si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    // populate other fields as needed...

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

    WCHAR szCmdLine[] = L"Console\\app.exe";
    if (CreateProcessW(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        // success...
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
    else
    {
        // error...
    }

    #else

    // handle other platforms as needed...

    #endif
}
```

Or, you can use the [`ShellExecute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew)/[`ShellExecuteEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) function instead, eg:

```cpp
#ifdef _Windows
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <FMX.Platform.Win.hpp>
#else
// include other platform headers as needed...
#endif

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    #ifdef _Windows

    HINSTANCE result = ShellExecuteW(
        Fmx::Platform::Win::FormToHWND(this),
        NULL, L"Console\\app.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    if (reinterpret_cast<INT_PTR>(result) > 32)
    {
        // success...
    }
    else
    {
        // error...
    }

    #else

    // handle other platforms as needed...

    #endif
}
```

```cpp
#ifdef _Windows
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <FMX.Platform.Win.hpp>
#else
// include other platform headers as needed...
#endif

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    #ifdef _Windows

    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = {};
    sei.cbSize = sizeof(sei);
    sei.hwnd = Fmx::Platform::Win::FormToHWND(this);
    sei.lpFile = L"Console\\app.exe";
    sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    // populate other fields as needed...

    if (ShellExecuteExW(&sei))
    {
        // success ...
    }
    else
    {
        // error...
    }

    #else

    // handle other platforms as needed...

    #endif
}
```

Comment: I keep getting I get "Not matching function for call to ShellExecuteW"

Comment: @murtdoc see my comment on Michael's answer about that issue.

Comment: for STARTUPINFOW i get the erro
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: Unable to perform incremental link - performing full link...

Comment: @murtdoc That has nothing to do with the code shown. The incremental linker just sucks in general, I always turn it off in the [project settings](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Linker).

Answer (score 1):

[ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) API (assuming you actually want to execute the file).

```
#include <shellapi.h>
ShellExecute(0,L"open",L"app.exe",0,0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: I cannot use ShellExecute in Rad Studio

Comment: Yes, you can. What is the actual problem you are having with it?

Comment: Why not ? It's standard Win32 API.

Comment: I get "Not matching function for call to ShellExecuteA"

Comment: @murtdoc You are calling the TCHAR-based `ShellExecute()` macro. The error message says `ShellExecuteA()` instead. That means your project has [_TCHAR maps to](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TCHAR_Mapping) set to `char`, thus `UNICODE` is not defined, causing `ShellExecute()` to map to `ShellExecuteA()` (and all other TCHAR-based macros to map to their `A` versions). Set the option to `wchar_t` instead, then `ShellExecute()` will map to `ShellExecuteW()` instead. Otherwise, just call `ShellExecuteW()` directly (as shown in my answer) instead of using the `ShellExecute()` macro.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I keep getting "Not matching function for call to ShellExecuteW"
and I included <shellapi.h>

Comment: @RemyLebeau   shellapi.h(88): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Fmx::Types::TWindowHandle *' to 'HWND' (aka 'HWND__ *') for 1st argument

Comment: @murtdoc you didn't say you are using FMX. I assumed VCL instead. I have updated your question and my answer accordingly. That is an important detail to omit. In FMX, a Form's `Handle` is not a Win32 `HWND`, like it is in VCL. In that case, you will have to use the [`FormToHWND()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/API:FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function declared in `<FMX.Platform.Win.hpp>`

Comment: and how do I run my exe with FormToHWND()? @RemyLebeau

Comment: @murtdoc you don't use `FormToHWND()` to run an exe. You use it to get your `TForm`'s Win32 `HWND` handle. See the update to my answer for how to use `FormToHWND()` with `ShellExecute/Ex()`.

Comment: I keep trying, but now I get
[bcc32c Error] LandingWindow.cpp(52): use of undeclared identifier 'FormToHWND'
@RemyLebeau

Comment: @RemyLebeau STARTUPINFOW compiles but it doesn't run the .exe
Nothing happens

Comment: @murtdoc `FormToHWND()` exists, look in `FMX.Platform.Win.hpp` for yourself. You might need to fully-qualify it, though (I've updated my answer to show that). In any case, don't use `FormToHWND()` with `CreateProcess()` as it doesn't take an `HWND`. `ShellExecute/Ex()` do, but they don't use `STARTUPINFOW`. Don't mix APIs unnecessarily. If the code compiles, but doesn't run the `.exe` file, then the APIs are likely failing. Read the docs I linked to in my answer, they explain how these APIs report errors. Is there an error code? My guess, you are likely using the wrong path to the `.exe` file.